# Function Targets Range of IDs

Tags: javascript, range, element

My current init() code targets element IDs starting at 'desc_1','desc_2','desc_3'...and so on.

```
function init(){
   var max = 50000;
   for (i = 1; i < max; i++){
      makeEditable('desc_'+i);}
}
```

Most of the elements on a page won't actually start at 1. For example, they might be 'desc_47','desc_48','desc_49' - or in some cases, aren't even sequential: 'desc_96','desc_99','desc_101'.

What would my init() statement have to be to target these types of element IDs?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using a class name instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of guessing at 50000 IDs, just select all elements that have an ID starting with `desc_`, then pass the element to `makeEditable()`.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll("*[id^=desc_]");

for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    makeEditable(els[i]);
}
```

If they're all the same element type, replace `*` in the selector with the tag name.

If there are other elements that start with that ID, then assign a class to the elements so you can target them directly.

If you can't add a class, then before passing it, you'd just need to test the `id` of each element to make sure it has a number at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for support for older browsers it could be done in the following way (maybe a little bit messy):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
        len = divs.length,
        myArray = [];

    for (var i = 0;i<len;i++)   {
        if (divs[i].id.substring(0,4) == "desc")    {
            makeEditable(divs[i]);
        }
    }
```